# Enthought Canopy and Tkinter

Tags: python-2.7, canopy

I'm kind new on programming and I have this book ThinkPython 2012 which I'm planning to finish, I'm on chapter 4 and it requires me to download this package http://thinkpython.com/swampy. It would be easy if I just use the normal python however I am using enthought canopy. Is it possible to get that package into the canopy? I'm using windows 7 64-bit but I'm using a 32-bit canopy.

Answer (score 0):

Should be straightforward. See these two articles on the Enthought support site:

https://support.enthought.com/entries/23389761-Installing-packages-into-Canopy-User-Python-from-the-OS-command-line
https://support.enthought.com/entries/21793229-Using-Tkinter-Turtle-in-Canopy-s-IPython-panel